# Override * operator in Rprofile.site to handle integer overflow

Tags: r

I'm trying to insert code into Rprofile.site to allow integers to be multiplied without overflowing.
**Careful if you run this code, it will overload the * operator. if you run it, you can store oldMult back into [tick][asterisk][tick] to set it back**

when I put this into Rprofile as follows

```
print("test1")
oldMult<-`*`
      `*`<-function(A,B){
        if(is.integer(A) || is.integer(B))
        {
          return(oldMult(as.numeric(A),as.numeric(B)))
        } else return (oldMult(A,B))
      }
print("test2")
.First <- function()
{
print("test3")
oldMult<-`*`
      `*`<-function(A,B){
        if(is.integer(A) || is.integer(B))
        {
          return(oldMult(as.numeric(A),as.numeric(B)))
        } else return (oldMult(A,B))
      }
print("test4")
#blah blah
}
```

I get this error

```
Error: cannot change value of locked binding for '*'
```

"test1" prints, oldMult shows up as

```
> oldMult
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("*")
```

but the strange part is, if I just run the exact same code

```
`*`<-function(A,B){
        if(is.integer(A) || is.integer(B))
        {
          return(oldMult(as.numeric(A),as.numeric(B)))
        } else return (oldMult(A,B))
      }
```

it works just fine

```
> as.integer(1000000000) * as.integer(1000000000)
[1] 1000000000000000000
```

what is different? does this have to do with environments?

```
> environmentIsLocked(.GlobalEnv)
[1] FALSE
> bindingIsLocked(*,.GlobalEnv)
Error: unexpected '*' in "bindingIsLocked(*"
> bindingIsLocked("*",.GlobalEnv)
Error in bindingIsLocked("*", .GlobalEnv) : no binding for "*"
> bindingIsLocked(`*`,.GlobalEnv)
Error in bindingIsLocked(`*`, .GlobalEnv) : not a symbol
```

Comment: Why are you doing the code twice in .Rprofile?  Why not just `source` your function(s) and be done with it?

Comment: I'd like to point out that environments are one thing, while NAMESPACEs are another. I would have expected any locking of the base functions to be applied to the base::NAMESPACE. However, I do not think that "*" is "locked". It's rather generic and you would be advised to study the `?Ops` page. Functions that need to be dispatched on the basis of both first and second arguments will need to be constructed with the S4 methods system.

Comment: I put it twice in rprofile because I'm not sure how that first{} function is supposed to work. the fact that it prints "test1" and nothing else should be sufficient to show what code actually executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> bindingIsLocked("*", env=baseenv())
[1] TRUE
```

Put `bindingIsLocked("*",environment())` in your funciton just before where you would override it. Then you will see whether it is locked in that local environment (`environment()`)